# Laravel - Issues trying to connect project to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm trying to connect laravel to the database, but I'm having issues.

I'm getting these errors:

> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
>         C:\Users\andre\Dropbox\College\Project\Rentable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 68
>
> 2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3308;dbname=rentable", "root", "", [])
>         C:\Users\andre\Dropbox\College\Project\Rentable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 68

This is my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3308
DB_DATABASE=rentable
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

This is a screenshot of the database on the localhost:

[image]

Comment: the db is configured to have a root password
change the configuration or add a password in your .env

Comment: Change the password to `DB_PASSWORD =' '`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the default password for local installations is either `root` , `secret` or `password`, try those in your `.env`

Answer (score 0):

Check your database parameters in config/database.php. You should have something like this

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_name'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'database_username'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'database_password'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```